# Update user object in parse.com

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

how can i update the user object in parse?i know must be logged with the user to modify itself for security reason. This is my code but don't works :POST https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User/xj3QLLYy07 400 (Bad Request)

```
      var user = Parse.User.current();
      console.log(user);

      user.save(null, {
      success: function(user) {

      user.set("email", "pty");

      user.save();
      }
       });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the `Parse.User` object, you need to explicitly set the email address like this (see the [API documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.User.html#setEmail)):

```
var user = Parse.User.current();
user.setEmail("email", options);
```

Comment: @Lucas is it possible to exclude options? so
user.setEmail("email");

Whats the correct prefix? I dont think I need options for what I'm doing

Comment: @Dano007 See http://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.User.html#setEmail. I think `options` is optional.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it did'nt seem to respond well. I used user.setEmail("email"); is that not correct?