# I am getting an error: TypeError: e.changes is undefined while updating the user object using Parse API. How to resolve this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

Below is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
  <html>
   <head>
    <title>Update Your Details</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.1.14.min.js"></script>
   </head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></tr>
        <tr><td>Work:</td><td><input type="text" name="work" id="work" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Education:</td><td><input type="text" name="edu" id="education" /></tr>
        <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /></td></tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <button id="save">Done</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">   

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#save').click(function(e) {
                //  e.preventDefault();
                    console.log("before2 clicked!");
                    Parse.initialize("XXXX","XXXX");
                    console.log("before clicked!");

                    var profileSave = Parse.User.current();

                    var userName = document.getElementById('name').value;
                    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
                    var work = document.getElementById('work').value;
                    var education = document.getElementById('education').value;
                    alert("userName = " + userName + "password = " + password + " work = " + work + " education " + education);
                    profileSave.setUsername("username", userName);
                    profileSave.setPassword("password", password);
                    profileSave.set("work", work);
                    profileSave.set("education", education);

                    profileSave.save(null, {
                        success: function(profileSave) {
                            profileSave.save();
                        },
                        error: function(profileSave, error) {
                            // Fail

                        }
                    });

                    alert("All the updates are being saved!");
                    window.open("welcome.html", '_self');
                });

            });
    </script>   

</body>

 </html>
```

I have searched on google and stackoverflow and the internet, but can't find the solution to my problem. In this code basically i want to update the details of the User Object which is currently logged in. But while updating it shows error specified above.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling `profileSave.save();` a second time in the success block? I believe this is the one causing the problem as there are no further changes at that time.

You can safely remove the extra `save()` call from the success block and everything should be fine.

Currently your code says "save these changes, and if it works, try and save a 2nd time with no additional changes".

Comment: actually i was referring to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614331/how-to-update-a-user-object-in-parse-com-not-create-a-new-record-object) ok i will see if that works..

Comment: Is the user already logged in? It seems like you're actually trying to create a new user, in which case you should be using the signUp() method instead. https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#users-signup

Comment: Yes the user is already logged in but i think that i am not creating new user as i am using "var profileSave = Parse.User.current();"... :(

Comment: OK i got it, thanks for your suggestion of using extra save() was problem, besides that the major problem was i guess i was using wrong syntax of setUsername function so now i am using set("username", string_which_is_to_set_As_username) and there is no problem.. :) except due to the last window.open("welcome.html", '_self'); i am getting "Cross-Origin Request Blocked"... :(